# Android EventListener

Tags: android, android-layout

Please check this xml

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/LayoutTab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_marginBottom="-30dip">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageMenu" android:background="@drawable/img_tab"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
                <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnNegative"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_minus_state" android:layout_margin="5dip"></ImageButton>
                <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnPositive"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_plus_state" android:layout_margin="5dip"></ImageButton>
                <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_share_state" android:layout_margin="5dip"></ImageButton>
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
```

here i am having an ImageView as a background and top of that there will be few image buttons. now i want to implement eventListener (OnClickListener) to the imageview & imagebuttons. but when i click on buttons, that event also goes to imageview (which is in the background) . how to handle this situation ?

**Edit: OP Posted Code in Comments**

```
mnuTab = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageMenu);
btnmin = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnNegative);
btnplus = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnPositive);
btnShare = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
mnuTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // my functions
    }
});
btnmin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { }
});
btnplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // my functions
    }
});
```

Comment: also goes to the imageView as in the imageButton's onClickListener gets called, and then the imageView's? Because if that's the case you should have the imageButton's onClickListener return true so that it consumes teh event and it doesn't get sent to the imageView

Comment: imagebutton never gets called. only imageview is getting triggered

Comment: It sounds like something is not set up properly with the listeners.  Can you provide the Java code where you set up these callbacks?

Comment: mnuTab = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageMenu); 
    btnmin = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnNegative); 
   btnplus = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnPositive); 
   btnShare = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);  mnuTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // my functions
   }
  });  
  btnmin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
   }
  });  
  btnplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // my functions
   }
  });

Comment: Also, what size are the images you are applying to these buttons?  It is possible the buttons you've created are too small to touch and so the event is getting passed through to the `ImageView`

Comment: yes. you are correct. problem came from the images which i am using it in my imagebutton. thank you very much for your hint. it's really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `ImageView` is very big so in `FrameLayout` it completely obscures your `LinearLayout`, so all the events go to `ImageView`? You can try to visually check your `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` boundaries in Eclipse in the UI Editor.
I also don't think using `FrameLayout` in your case is a good idea, `FrameLayout` is usually used to make one UI element visible while all the others invisible to provide a kind of UI switcher which is not the case here. It seems you can remove `FrameLayout`, set the background image to your `LinearLayout` instead and process everything in your `ImageViews` handlers then.